# CSS design like Border Radius

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am wondering if this is possible using border radius.

[image]

What I want is if I click the menu I want the active state to be something like this. But I don't know if it's possible using border radius.

The only code I have done so far is using the

```
 border-radius:10px;
```

but what I want is something like that on the image.

Comment: Post the code what you tried sofar?

Comment: @G.L.P the only code I have search so far is the `border-radius`.

Comment: @G.L.P is there any code like border radius that will give you similar results like that in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo element and make a triangle which overlaps over the menu item with menu background color:

For eg:

```css
li{
  position: relative;
  }
li:after{
       content: "";
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
       border-style: solid;
       border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;/*manage px values from 20 to what your need suits*/
       border-color: transparent #007bff transparent;/*use menu bg color instead of #007bff*/
       position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>menu item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8rojeghd/2/)**

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li class="active">Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:#E7D7B7;
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 50px 5px 5px;
}
ul li.active {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background-color:#CA8E26;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    padding-right:50px;
}
li.active:after {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 28px 28px 0;
    border-color: transparent #E7D7B7 transparent transparent;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Upto my knowledge, its not advisable to use border-radius. might be pseudo Elements will work. You can adjust border width (28px) according to `li's`  height and padding. Use border color as menu bar color. so it will merge with background.

Comment: Thanks you are a great help.. =)

Answer (score -2):

Try `border-right: 30px solid transparent;` on `active` state.
I think this will solve your problem.